# Android - ExpandableListView in ScrollView

Tags: android, listview, layout, scrollview, expandablelistview

Ok, i know this isn't to do, but i need to do it!
My layout is this : [image]

When a group is tapped and the text is shown the view increases its height and, having a scroll view, it scrolls. When the user scrolls, the image is scrolled also, so if the text under the group tapped is too long, the image scrolls.
I'm sure there is a way to do it.
I'm a newbie of Android, i'm an iOS dev.

EDIT :
This is the result i want, just like in the iOS version of this app :

[image]

This is the standard view when the user open this layout.

[image]

And this is when the user open a group of the expandable list and scroll to read all the text.

This is what i want.

Comment: what you want to do ? you dont want to scroll image and want to set your image at background....

Comment: means your one activity will contain one image but having different text which will be in listview and you want to move your text but not image.

Comment: ONe more thing i want to know is you are adding your image view in header of listview or not.

Comment: @BharatSharma yes, but image and text (the expandable view) are in a scroll view, so the result when the text is opened is similar to the last photo. In Android it isn't possible to realize O_O

Comment: no, it isn't in header, is a separate element

Comment: if you have defined scollview in your layout then remove you scrollview so that default exapandable listview's scrollview can come....

Comment: yes, but the image doesn't scroll if isn't part of the listview. So, when the text is opened the view scroll, but the image stand in its position, scrolling only the expandable view.

Comment: If you will keep your image in a different scrollview then your image can also be scroll. Problem is that you cannot have nested scrollview means you cannot put one scrollview into another in android..

Comment: i know, but there isn't another way?? Is it possible to set a header on a ExpandableListView? A scrollable header of course

Comment: The best way i thought is devide your screen in half part keep imageview in your first half part with a scrollview. In second half keep expandable listview. In thisway your imageview and listview both can be scrolled independently side by side

Comment: @BharatSharma but listview and image doesn't scroll at the same time

Comment: @BharatSharma it's impossible there isn't a solution..

Comment: I have worked on listview but till now not found. android does not allow to nest scrollview. Expandable listview have its own scrollview and if you will insert scrollview in its header then only one scrollview will work either outer or inner...